# How to Mark Pictures as Favorites

Tags: file-management, images, photography, image-viewer

I have recently downloaded 100's of thousands of of classical paintings, all in the public domain.  They are organized very well already, but **I want to be able to select individual images and "star" them or mark them as "favorite" pictures**.

Some things I want to avoid:

- Making copies of the files and placing them in a "favorites" folder; I hate file duplication.
- Modifying the image file itself.  The files are part of a torrent, so I can't modify the original files and seed them at the same time.

I'm starting to think my best bet is to use something like Picasa or Google Photos, but I don't use Google Drive, I use Microsoft OneDrive.  Also, I really don't want a photo library program that makes ".picasa" files or ".DS_Store" files or any other nonsense files scattered all across my file systems.

**TL;DR,**  I'm looking for a way to keep track of a few hundreds of favorite pictures within a library of 100's of thousands without modifying the original files in any way, and without creating thousands of ".picasa" type files in each folder.

Thank you for your time reading this.

Answer (score 1):

[XNView MP](https://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/#downloads) - it stores favorites (tags or ratings/colors) in a database and works on Mac that you seem to be using.

Comment: This is my recommendation as well.  It is cross-platform, and will run on macOS, Linux, and Windows.